# Access Microsoft dynamics online CRM through web api

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am new to microsoft & dynamics CRM online API... I am really getting confused how to access CRM online API's. I just implemented [based on this](http://mscrmshop.blogspot.in/2016/01/crm-web-api-and-cors-support.html) and I see this works.

But is there any proper documentation to connect all the modules of dynamics online CRM through API... In the image, I have marked the things I need to have

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't really clear what you are trying to do. "Access the online api"... to do what? Just login? Query data? DML?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt593051.aspx) to Microsoft's documentation on how to use the Web API.

From the docs, this is how you retrieve an entity:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)
```

Replace `accounts` with the schema name of the entity you're trying to retrieve. The guid represents the id of the record you're retrieving. Replace `8.2` with your CRM's API version.

I'm assuming you want to retrieve an entity from your text: *Need to have these things through API*